# How to find cause of exception if type is Throwable

Tags: java, inheritance, types

Give this method here:

```
public SomeClass(Throwable stackTrace) {
    super();
    this.stackTrace = stackTrace;
}
```

How can I find out what class type `stacktrace` originally was before being passed in?

Comment: the `stackTrace` is *still* the original type - it's just that your code block refers to it by a parent class

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
stacktrace.getClass().getName()
```

or

```
stacktrace instanceof CLASS_YOU_WANT_TO_TRY
```

Answer (score 0):

You make this determination by handling exceptions as explicitly as possible. That includes not ever, *EVER*, catching `Throwable` and handling exceptions as near to the code that threw it as possible. I'm not sure what you're trying to do by constructing a POJO with a `Throwable` but it's probably not a path that will lead you to much enlightenment.